# Posting data over web services using Java, Ajax and json is not working

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, web-services

Could somebody help me with this. This goes always to error, no error message though, just the console.log. Is there any good way to debug this or could you just see what's wrong in this?

Thanks!
Sami

```
function foo(){

        alert('Button pressed');
        var user={"id":10,"firstName":" Ted","lastName":"TESTING","age":69,"freeText":"55555","weight":55};

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/testSoft/webresources/entity.user/",
        dataType: "json",
        data: user,

        success: function(data){alert(data);},
        error: function(data) {
        console.log('#####################error:################################'+data);                 
        alert('addUser error: ' + data.firstName);
        }
        });
        };
```

Web service:

```
@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(User entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}
```

User

```
public class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "lastName")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "age")
private Integer age;
@Lob
@Size(max = 65535)
@Column(name = "freeText")
private String freeText;
@Column(name = "weight")
private Integer weight;
```

Comment: So what does ' just the console.log' tell you? Does the request reach your server-side application? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: #####################error:################################[object Object] (19:50:22:273) alert('addUser error: ' + data.firstName); says error: undefiened. What is the best tool for debugging javaScritp+ webservices?

Comment: Have you put a break point in your controller action to verify it's even being called? Also, typically I see urls ending in '.something' to indicate the type of data the client is requesting, is '.user' a custom format you're trying to implement?

Comment: INFO: ----User.java constructor called in server-side-----
INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class java.lang.String but it never goes to create method or its mother class  @POST
    
    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    public void create(User entity) {
        System.out.println("-----------------------------create user in UserFacadeREST------------------------");
        super.create(entity);
    }                                                                 If somebody is using NB 7.3RC2 could you check should your rest-services be in Services tab under Server-webservices?I havent

Comment: @BrMcMullin. It goes to server side, but not the create-method. When I test web service in browser http://localhost:8080/testSoft/webresources/entity.user I got nice xml list of users.

Answer (score 0):

PLS tell me why this is working outside the function? If I insert function call to button like that, it is not working:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddUser" onclick="foo()">Register</button>
```

BUT it is working when it is outside of the function:

```
<script>
            var user={"id":10,"firstName":" Coka","lastName":"CocaCola","age":69,"freeText":"55555","weight":55};
            alert('user----->' +user.firstName);
            $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/testSoft/webresources/entity.user/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(user),

            success: function(data){alert(data);},
            error: function(data) {
            console.log('#####################error:################################'+data);                 
            alert('addUser error: ' + data.firstName);
            }
            });
        </script>
```

I am so bad in JS and I hate it as well, now even more :(